# jQuery dynamic id value returning UNDEFINED in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get **WordPress** `Post Id` **dynamically** as variable in `jQuery`. However, it is returning the value undefined when I try to debug in `console`. Can anyone help me on this ?

**Here's the code:**

**data-id attribute displaying id of the current post**

```
<?php $id = get_the_id(); ?>

 <button data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" type="button" class="book btn btn-danger">
    Submit
</button>
```

**My jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
jQuery('.packageForm').submit(packageSubmit);     
        function packageSubmit(){
           var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
           var ceccForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: ceccForm,
            success:function(data){
            console.log(id);
            console.log(data);
            jQuery(".response").html(data);
            jQuery(".packageForm")[0].reset();
            jQuery('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            }
        });

      return false;
      }
 });
```

Here, I am using `var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');` to get the value of the attribute `data-id` dynamically. It's showing the message **Undefined Value** in the browsing console.

**Any help ?**

Comment: Console log `jQuery(this)` in your submit handler and you will see why

Comment: actually `.packageForm` is my Form CLass `<form method="post" class="packageForm clearfix">`. I don't think it has nothing to do with that. Or has it ?

Comment: Exactly, so `jQuery(this)` is your form element, and not your button element which is the one with the data attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `this` is actually referring to your form `packageForm` since you're calling it from the submit function of the form, and it won't have the attribute you've set to the button.

You could probably do something like this

```
var id = jQuery(this).find('button.book').data('id');
```

Comment: Hello @H77, id is showing only the first element of the loop. I am using other buttons as well, and they all have the different values but the log is showing the same id i.e. *49*

Comment: Do you want to get all the ids? Can you post an example of your resulting html?

Comment: himalayanbodycare.com, you can see here. Go to the Our Package section and try to book the package. The very first package is working fine, but the others are not resetting the form values. That's my issue .. :)

Comment: Updated the answer. Based on the site this should work.

Answer (score 1):

this refers to the form not the button

do a [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the button if the button is in the form tag

```
jQuery(this).find('button.book').attr('data-id');
```